# ruby on rails directory browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to write a simple RoR app that lists all directories in a specific path then allows me to click that file or directory to either open the file or open the directory. I'm using the following code which works to list the directories but I can't figure out how to open the file or directory from here. When clicking the directory I get a "No route matches [GET] "/selected file" error.

```
controller
    @file = Dir.foreach ("/specifiedpath/")

view
<% @file.each do |file| %> 
    <tr>
        <td><%= link_to file, file %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please include the route(s) from config/routes.rb in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need something in your `routes.rb` that looks like this:

```
get '/browse/*path' => 'browse#show', as: :browse
```

In your `browse_controller`, you'll want a `show` action that does something like:

```
class BrowseController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @path = params[:path] || '/some/default'
    @files = Dir.foreach(path)
  end
```

Finally, in your `browse/show.html.haml` (I prefer HAML, sorry) view, something like:

```
- @files.each do |file|
  %tr
    %td= link_to file, browse_path(File.join(@path, file))
```

(Pardon me if it all doesn't work outright—haven't time to fully test a fleshed out solution right now—but I can delve into it a little more if you have trouble getting it to work yourself.)

Comment: Thanks I will work with this and let you know. Appreciate the quick reply!

Comment: There are some risks in exposing your directory structure to malicious coders.  i.e. if they were to pass variables for other areas of the site.  You probably want to think about limiting the scope of the query